# Xcode 7 Storryboard layout issue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7

I startet to move my app to iOS9 and loaded my Project in Xcode 7.

When I Run it on my device I get this:
[image]

The Size class is set to: w:Compact h:Regular
In the Preview everything looks normal.

In the Simulator is no element showing up at all.

Do you have an idea or similar problems?

Thank you
reptil1990

Comment: What device are you running the app on?

Comment: iPhone 6.... the layout is looking like iPhone 4